# Futura Condensed ExtraBold not working in ios 8 with UIFontDescriptor

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

The target font (`Futura Condensed ExtraBold`) is not set correctly with the following codes. It seems that the font is not loaded at all.

```
UIFontDescriptor *futura = [UIFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithFontAttributes:@{UIFontDescriptorFamilyAttribute:@"Futura"}];
UIFontDescriptor *condensedBoldFutura = [futura fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitCondensed|UIFontDescriptorTraitBold];
self.headerLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:condensedBoldFutura size:40];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, which is a workaround.

```
UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [UIFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithFontAttributes:
                                    @{
                                      @"NSFontFamilyAttribute" : @"Futura",
                                      @"NSFontFaceAttribute" : @"Bold Condensed"
                                      }];
self.myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontDescriptor size:40];
```

Comment: `Condensed ExtraBold` works now, any idea why traits not working?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure that you are using the correct name of font, it will work.
Please set using this:

> [self.myLabel setFont:[UIFont
>   fontWithName:@"Futura-CondensedExtraBold" size:20.0f]];

It will work for all iOS :)